# Validating Sum of InlineFormSet against Total in ParentModel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Let's assume I have a main model called **Bill**. There I have a field **total_amount** and a many-to-many relationship to the **UserModel** through an intermediate model, where the **share of the total bill per User** can be recorded. See the following snippets. Finally, the sum of **the share of the totall bill per User**'s shall equal the **total_amount**.

I like to validate within the form, inlineform (or model) that the sum of the amounts in the Model BillDebitor equals the total_amount of the Bill Model. If anyhow possible this shall be evaluated within the form itself and raise a ValidationError if the amounts are not equal. Can somebody assist in how to solve this? I tried throgh custom clean methods, but for some reason neighter the parent form nor the inline formsets are available in the respective forms.

**models.py**

```
class Bill(modles.Model):
   total_amount = models.Decimalfield()
   debtor = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='BillDebtor')

class BillDebtor(models.Model):
   bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill)
   debtor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   amount = models.Decimalfield()
```

**forms.py**

```
class BaseBillForm(models.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Bill
      fields = ['total_amount']

class DebtorForm(models.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = BillDebtor
      fields = ['debtor', 'amount']

class DebtorFormSet(models.BaseInlineFormSet):
   pass

DebtorInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Bill, BillDebtor, 
                                            form=BaseBillForm, 
                                            formset=DebtorFormSet, extra=2)
```

**view.py**

```
class SplitBillView(CreateView):
   model = Bill
   from_class = BaseBillForm

   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      if self.request.POST:
          context['formset_debtor'] = DebtorInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
      else:
          context['formset_debtor'] = DebtorInlineFormSet()
      return context
   
   def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()

        context = self.get_context_data()
        debtors = context['formset_debtor']

        with transaction.atomic():
           if debtors.is_valid():
              debtors.instance = self.object
              debtors.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally got it. It seems impossible to access the inline formsets from the parent form (and also the other way round).

So the only place where they both come together is the view.

This is what I did (I highly appreciate ideas in term of better code design, it looks a bit messy to me):

view.py

```
class SplitBillView(CreateView):
   model = Bill
   from_class = BaseBillForm

   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      if self.request.POST:
          context['formset_debtor'] = DebtorInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
      else:
          context['formset_debtor'] = DebtorInlineFormSet()
      return context
   
   def form_valid(self, form):
      # Get the total Amount
      total_amount = form.cleaned_data['total_amount']
      # Get the Inline Formset
      context = self.get_context_data()
      debtors = context['formset_debtor']

      with transaction.atomic():
         if debtors.is_valid():
            sub_total = sum(sub_amount['amount'] for sub_amount in debtors.cleaned_data)
            if total_amount == sub_total:
               self.object = form.save()
               owners.instance = self.object
               owners.save()
            else:
               form.add_error(None, 'Sum of debtors must match total amount!')
               return super().form_invalid(form)
         else:
            return super().form_invalid(form)
      return super().form_valid(form)
```